# A SQL Join returns duplicate data and messes with SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, duplicates

I've been regressively testing my bulletin board I recently developed. I came across a small bug in my SQL query.

```
SELECT `user`.avatar, `user`.username, `user`.id AS user_id, `post`.title, 
       `post`.id, `post`.date AS post_date, `comment`.date AS last_comment_date
FROM `post`
INNER JOIN `user` ON `post`.user_id = `user`.id
LEFT JOIN `comment` ON `post`.id = `comment`.post_id
WHERE `post`.category_id = 1
ORDER BY IFNULL(`last_comment_date`, `post_date`) DESC;
```

Will produce something like;

[image: duplicate data]

I happen to know the cause of this. MySQL joins all the comments with their post, in other words, its a one to many relationship, a post can have many comments. This creates issues with pagination as the first ten posts could be the same depending on whether or not it has ten comments. I happen to only need the latest comment date from the `comment` table.

I came across a couple of solutions.

- Group by `post.id` but it doesn't work as the order by executed after the rows have grouped.
- Retrieve the entire result set and sort through what I need with PHP. Using this method I'd probably take a massive performance hit.
- Doing multiple queries but this is not considered idea.
- Doing a subquery but I don't know if this is a bad practice or not.

What is the best thing to do? Is there anyway to stop MySQL from returning duplicate data on a join if it is a one to many relationship?

**EDIT 1**

As @Zane asked, this SQL query...

```
SELECT `user`.avatar, `user`.username, `user`.id AS user_id, `post`.title, `post`.id, 
`post`.date AS post_date, MAX(`comment`.date) 
FROM `post` 
INNER JOIN `user` ON `post`.user_id = `user`.id 
LEFT JOIN `comment` ON `post`.id = `comment`.post_id 
WHERE `post`.category_id = 1 
GROUP BY `post`.id 
ORDER BY IFNULL(MAX(`comment`.date), `post_date`) DESC
```

produces;

[image: non-duplicate data]

Which seems like exactly what I want. The posts are being sorted by the latest comment date if they have comments *(or post date)* if they don't. I can use this with pagination `LIMITS` as well without any preprocessing. Do I still need `IFNULL`? I'd think so.

**EDiT 2**

There is still a defect. If a post has a NULL last_comment_date it doesn't sort correctly. If you refer to the the image below. You can see that the last_comment_date is sitting there even though a bump should've occurred.

[image: doesn't sort properly]

Please ignore what's below.

---

**EDIT 3**

This is what I want.

[image: what I need]

Comment: I know this doesn't directly address your problem but for future reference don't use reserved names like `user` for the your column names.

Comment: Have you tried using `MAX()` for comment date and then `Group by` the rest of your columns?

Comment: +1 Ahh thanks for the comment! I didn't realize this was a reserve keyword. D: That's why its color coded when I type it. I have plans of modifying the structure a bit regardless of it being needed.

Comment: @Zane are u sure `user` is a reserved keyword ?

Comment: @Zane please refer to my edit above. Do you mean like that? Would I still need ifnull? I think I would because not every post will have a comment, thanks! Also Abhik I do believe so. It color coded when I type it into a SQL editor.

Answer (score 2):

I think the GROUP BY is your best choice. Simply group by all selected columns except comment.date and use MAX-function to get the latest comment date like this:

```
SELECT
    `user`.avatar,
    `user`.username,
    `user`.id AS user_id,
    `post`.title,
    `post`.id,
    `post`.date AS post_date,
    MAX(`comment`.date) AS last_comment_date

FROM
    `post` INNER JOIN `user` ON `post`.user_id = `user`.id
    LEFT JOIN `comment` ON `post`.id = `comment`.post_id

WHERE
    `post`.category_id = 1

GROUP BY
    `user`.avatar,
    `user`.username,
    `user`.id,
    `post`.title,
    `post`.id,
    `post`.date

ORDER BY
    IFNULL(`last_comment_date`, `post_date`) DESC;
```

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. Right now I only used your original idea, it sorts by last comment date, but if this is null uses post date, actually that is what your screenshot is showing. Maybe you want to first sort by last comment date (with nulls to the end) and second by post date?

Comment: See edit #3 above, compare it against the image in edit #2. This is what I want. Is this possible with SQL? I think I've tried sorting by last comment date and then post date.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why is post id 2 ranked before 1 and not before 3? For both (1 and 2) the last action (post date OR last comment date) was before post of 3. So both should be either before OR after 3. For me there seems to be no order right now.

Comment: Correction: why is post id 3 ranked before 1 and not before 2?

Comment: If you look, post with id of 2 has a more recent comment date than the `date` of the post with id of 3. Even though it was created at "2014-03-13 13:49:46" the id of 2 has a comment dated "2014-03-13 01:09:57". Oh wait, my bad! I forgot to actually comment on the post with id of 2. Now it is more recent than the post of id with 3. Thanks you for all your help! =)

Comment: Your welcome! May I add or change something to the answer or is it what finally solved your problem?

Comment: Sure go ahead. I like more information, more information is good haha.